# TextView get cuts off when I try to animate long single line text

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to create text slider. But the problem I facing is the text get cut off because the text don't fit the screen. How can I force android to not cut the text. I tried

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

in the layout but it dosen't work.

Please give me hit on how to do ?

Comment: What do you want it to do instead?  Wrap to another line?  Shrink the font?

Comment: I want to keep the font size. I don't want the text to get cut off so when it translate from left to right the user can see all the text. Like what they do in news channel. they have headline bar when there is a text sliding with all the headline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the textview in a HorizontalScrollView

Than programatically autoscroll the scrollview by calling the smoothscrollto method

Comment: No problem :D If you're satisfied with the answer could you please vote it best answer? :D

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I also found good example here https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo that give how to do.